# [useless] :rosrun tf view_frames

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am unable to execute the following commmand in order to view my tf tree

```
rosrun tf view_frames
```

which return the following error:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named view_frames below /opt/ros/groovy/share/tf
```

Is it becaue tf is updated and thus, there is other ways to view the tf tree? what is the command then?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65054/%5Buseless%5D-:rosrun-tf-view_frames/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What version of ros are you using? in Groovy it is just `view_frames`.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-13**:
thank you verymuch. I am actually using view_frames

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-13**:
and do you know where is the generated pdf?

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-06-13**:
never mind. The location of the pdf is actually the curent directory of the running terminal

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2013-06-13**:
In the current location of the terminal.  So if you just open a terminal, it would be in the home directory.